# Why excel SUMIF with range criteria does not work as expected?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns A, B, C. Now, I want to get the sum for each cell Ai where
Bi < Ci

**Example:**

```
A    B    C
-----------
2    1    3
4    5    4
3    2    7
6    6    6
-----------

Expected result = A1 + A3 = 2 + 3 = 5
```

I tried the following formula: `=SUMIF(B1:B4,"<C1:C4",A1:A4)`,
but it gives me 0 !

Anyone could help ?

Comment: Your C1:C4 is part of a string as you put it between the " ". See jblood94 for the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this array formula:

```
{=SUM(IF(B1:B4<C1:C4,A1:A4))}
```

You'll need to apply it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You know that you set the array formula correctly when you see the curly brackets around the formula

Comment: Other guy was faster, so I had to come up with something new :)

Comment: Or `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4*--(B1:B4<C1:C4))`, no need for [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [Enter]

Answer (score 3):

The `SUMIF` function accepts 3 arguments: `range`, `criteria`, and `sum_range`.

If you check [the documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b), you'll notice that while `range` and `sum_range` both accept a "range of cells" (i.e. multiple values), `criteria` is a **single value**, the same thing compared against all of the cells in `range`.  If you *do* put a Range or Array in, then it will only use the **first** item.
**{EDIT}** *Unless the entire function is part of an Array Calculation, in which case you will get an array of `SUMIF` for each item in the Array - e.g. `{=SUM(SUMIF(A1:A4,{1,2}))}` is the same as `{=SUM({SUMIF(A1:A4,1), SUMIF(A1:A4,2)})}`*

This means, you can do `=SUM(B1:B4,"<" & MIN(C1:C4),A1:A4)` to add up where the values in column A where the value in column B is smaller than *all* the values in column C, but for a row-by-row comparison you will need an Array Formula or `SUMPRODUCT`, like so:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4*--(B1:B4<C1:C4))
```

Comment: Although it is true that such row-by-row comparisons are beyond the capability of SUMIF(S)/COUNTIF(S), etc., it might be worth clarifying that the criteria parameter CAN accept a range of values. Provided the SUMIF (for example) is wrapped within some suitable, coercing function, it will accept, and operate over, a range of values passed as the criteria parameter: =SUM(SUMIF(B1:B4,{1,2},A1:A4)), for example, returns 5 using the dataset provided.